# Whats the difference between Reference and Pointer return types in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, coding-style, address-operator

If I were to create a simple object in C++, what is the difference between returning an address of the member vs. returning a pointer. As far as I'm aware, C++ doesn't have automatic garbage collection so it wouldn't be keeping a reference count. So why would someone do it this way:

```
class CRectangle {
public:
    string& getName( );
    int&    getWidth( );
    int&    getHeight( );
private:
    string  name;
    int     height;
    int     width;
};
```

rather than this way:

```
class CRectangle {
public:
    string* getName( );
    int*    getWidth( );
    int*    getHeight( );
private:
    string  name;
    int     height;
    int     width;
};
```

I realize these would allow you to access member data, but I'm not concerned about proper encapsulation in this simple example. So whats the difference? Speedup? Readability? Style?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `&` (in this context) doesn't mean "address of".

A function declared as `string& getName( );` returns a *reference*, not a pointer. A reference is essentially an alias for another object. So in this case, it doesn't return a copy of the object's name, or a pointer to the name, but a reference to the name *itself*. So any changes to the returned object are directly applied to the object's name.

You could achieve the same by returning a pointer, but there'd be two significant differences:

- a pointer requires special syntax to access (the `*` and `->` operators), whereas a reference is used the exact same way you'd use the object itself.
- a pointer can be `null`, a reference cannot. So any time a pointer is used, you are signalling to the reader of the code that "this value may be `null`"

Comment: Hi, just wondering,  if I declare `CRectangle rec`, and I call `rec.getName()`, for his first version (return by reference), does the function call return a reference to rec?

Comment: I am just curious what object the `string &` refers to?

Answer (score 10):

In this context, the `&` means reference - not address-of.

- A pointer can be 0 - A reference cannot, in a well-formed program.
- Ownership may be more unclear when you return a pointer.
- Readability is subjective - I'd say use a reference when you can.
- For efficiency, there's no real difference.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the & form is called a "reference" in C++. The * form is called "pointer" or 
"address of".

Speedup - no difference. Readability - probably a slight advantage for references, no derefencing in the upstack code.

Style - explicit breaking of encapsulation is bad enough style to obbscure anything else. If you want an object with naked data, an all-public struct would do just as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no benefit I can think of in returning a pointer to an integer from a property-type method such as `getWidth()`. It adds the burden of having to track memory ownership; but is actually likely to increase the bandwidth of the return type (both `int` and pointer sizes are platform specific, and can and do vary, but typical sizes are 32 and 64 bits respectively).